# Linq "where" condition with nullable object property result in "invoke non static method requires a target"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, exception, asp.net-mvc-3

I've tried to find a similar question but I haven't found exactly what I want.
I have this issue: about the following code I am not able to find a way to manage that if `devTab` is null then his property `ID` is not available and the `where` condition `t.IDDevTab ==devTab.ID` leads to `null reference error`. Mind that t.IDDevTab is not nullable in the DB. I have tried to insert some additional conditions to the `Where` but it resulted in error: `invoke non static method requires a target`. I would obtain a empty list in "DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc" if "devTab" is null!

```
DeviceTable devTab = (from t in _db.DeviceTables
                      where t.DeviceType == devtype && t.IDPlant == id
                      select t)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

var DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc = (from t in _db.DeviceTabCols
                                   where t.IDDevTab == devTab.ID
                                       && t.MeasureFamily != "KEY"
                                       && t.MeasureFamily != "DATETIME"
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       colName = t.ColumnName,
                                       colDescr = t.ColumnDescr
                                   })
                                   .ToList();
```

Is there a workaround of this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *is there a workaround of this problem?* - sure, don't try to reference a property on a null instance. What do you  *actually* want to do if devTab is null? If there is no `devTab` then `where t.IDDevTab ==devTab.ID` doesn't make sense, so what should be done instead? Or should we not attempt to look up the second query at all?

Comment: Good point, exactly the list is used joined with another and if "devTab" is null it should expect DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc is an empty list! Maybe the entire code is not designed perfectly I admit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if devTab is null you want a new empty list of anonymous type.. Awkward, but doable:

```
DeviceTable devTab = (from t in _db.DeviceTables
                  where t.DeviceType == devtype && t.IDPlant == id
                  select t)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

var DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc = devTab == null ?
  Enumerable.Empty<object>().Select(x => new { colName = "", colDescr = "" }).ToList() :
  (
    from t in _db.DeviceTabCols
    where t.IDDevTab == devTab.ID && t.MeasureFamily != "KEY" && t.MeasureFamily != "DATETIME"
    select new {
      colName = t.ColumnName,
      colDescr = t.ColumnDescr
    }
  ).ToList();
```

If you wanted to switch away from anonymous types in this case, you could look at ValueTuple:

```
var DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc = devTab == null ?
  new List<(string colName, string colDesc)>() :
  (
    from t in _db.DeviceTabCols
    where t.IDDevTab == devTab.ID && t.MeasureFamily != "KEY" && t.MeasureFamily != "DATETIME"
    select (
      colName: t.ColumnName,
      colDescr: t.ColumnDescr
    )
  ).ToList();
```

Or make a record, which is like a class but with some extra bits that make it useful as a data holder:

```
//defined in a namespace
public record ColThing(string ColName, string ColDesc);

var DeviceTabColumnsNameAndDesc = devTab == null ?
  new List<ColThing>() :
  (
    from t in _db.DeviceTabCols
    where t.IDDevTab == devTab.ID && t.MeasureFamily != "KEY" && t.MeasureFamily != "DATETIME"
    select new ColThing(t.ColumnName, t.ColumnDescr)
  ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. The fact of the awkward request is due to edit the code the less is possible to obtain an extended version where the original solution did not cover it. In practice maintaining the anonymous types avoided me to define a lot of structures.

Comment: ATs are great for temporary data needs but for more complex stuff you can look at something like `ValueTuple` or `record`. I'll add a bit into the answer